# Problem with installing Postgresql on Mac OS. After reboot system. A non-fatal error occur whilst creating menu shortcuts

Tags: postgresql, macos

I have some problems with install psql.  I don't know what to do. I searched all solutions, buy doesn't found. OS: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm22g.png)Big Sur 11.2.2
Look screenshoots [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGNne.png)

//a non-fatal error occur whilst creating menu shortcuts.
//problem running post-install step. installation may not complete correctly failed to start the database server.

Comment: First you are trying to install Postgresl not psql as psql is the command line client for Postgresql. Second where are you installing Postgres from?

Comment: Installed from “enterprisedb.com”. So, the first I should install psql, then install Postgres?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Running into same problem

Answer (score -1):

I also ran into this issue trying to use the EnterpriseDB installer on a 2015 Air running Big Sur 11.2.3 and could not solve it.
I used Homebrew to install instead and had no issue. There are tutorials available to install using Homebrew. E.g. https://dev.to/letsbsocial1/installing-pgadmin-only-after-installing-postgresql-with-homebrew-part-2-4k44